# Changing parameter in a Mathematica-defined function

Tags: special-functions

I would like to use `EllipticTheta` with the sum running on the integers with a specific step. Is there a way to do that? To be more precise, I am trying to expand the following function
    $$\Theta_{\ell,k}(\tau,z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}+\frac{\ell}{2k}}q^{k n^2}e^{2\pi i z k n}\,,$$
with    $q=e^{2\pi i \tau }$. I was thinking of using EllipticTheta[3, k   $\pi$ z,    $q^{2k}$] but I don't know how to make the sum go in steps of    $n+\frac{\ell}{2k}$. If I was to define it by hand, I would adjust the exponent and that's it:
`theta[q_, z_, l_, k_] := Refine[Sum[q^(k(n + l/(2 k))^2) Exp[2 \[Pi] I k (n + l/(2 k)) z], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}], {Element[n, Integers], Element[l, Integers], Element[k, Integers]}];`
but maybe there's a more elegant solution using EllipticTheta. Any idea?